# how to use same method with different Input parameters

Tags: c#, user-controls, overloading

I have a UC - DropdownUC . It gets filled from service from below method ,and this method is called from pageload

```
private void InitDropdown(DropdownUC ddlUC, DropdownUC.ParameterKey paramKey, bool enabled = true)
    {
        Log.Debug("private void InitDropdown(DropdownUC ddlUC, DropdownUC.ParameterKey paramKey, bool enabled = true)");
        Log.Debug("ddlUC: [object]");
        Log.Debug("paramKey: [object]");
        Log.Debug("enabled: " + enabled.ToString());

        ddlUC.InitializeDropdownSelect();
        ddlUC.FillDropdownUC(paramKey, false);
        ddlUC.Enabled = enabled;
    }
```

now i need to a differnt kind of UC - MultiSelectDropDownUC it is checkbox list while the previous one was drop down list. I wish to re-use the above method. How can i do it?

```
InitDropdown(ddlAssignedtoMultiUser,MultiSelectDropDownUC.ParameterKey.Type);
```

the above assignment gives me error. How can i resuse the InitDropdown method???

Comment: what is `ddlAssignedtoMultiUser`

Comment: send argument missmatched in definition second argument is `DropdownUC.ParameterKey` and while calling send argument is `MultiSelectDropDownUC.ParameterKey.Type`